# How to map arbitrary JSON object into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate to store objects that have a pre-defined structure in MySQL.  I am familiar with this process.  What I want to do is store an arbitrary JSON object that I don't know the structure of and still be able to get decent select speed.

For instance lets say I want to store an object like this for multiple users:

```
{
    "number": 7,
    "name": "Doug",
    "over18": true,
    "favoriteColors": [
        1,
        4,
        5
    ]
}
```

I was thinking of something like this for a MySQL table structure

(int)id, (int)parentId, (varchar)name, (bool)boolVal, (double)doubleVal, (varchar)stringVal, (enum)type

This object would be represented like this

```
1, null, "root"  , null, null, null  , 'object'
2, 1   , "number", null, 7.0 , null  , 'number'
3, 1   , "name"  , null, null, "Doug", 'string'
4, 1   , "over18", true, null, null  , 'bool'
5, 1   , "favclr", null, null, null  , 'array'
6, 5   , null    , null, 1.0 , null  , 'number'
7, 5   , null    , null, 4.0 , null  , 'number'
8, 5   , null    , null, 5.0 , null  , 'number'
```

Can anybody please advise as to this technique.  Is there already a library out there that can accomplish this?  thanks!

Comment: What you've described is known as the EAV (entity attribute value) Model, and is generally discouraged as being and 'anti-pattern'. It's usually better use a properly normalised relational database schema. But take a look at MongoDB or CouchDB, which may actually be perfect for you.